# how to add something to python to give you a warning if you're about to print over 1000 lines

Tags: python, printing

I'm using ipython notebook. I use a lot of print statements when I'm debugging, but sometimes I print too much by accident and it freezes my computer. Is there a way to turn on something that tells python to give you a warning if you're about to print over 10000 chars?

UPDATE:
thanks everyone for the excellent thoughts. I'll look into logging.

Comment: `s=what_ur_gonna_print(); if len(s)<len_I_will_print: print s`

Comment: Do you really want to do that? Otherwise, consider using `logging` instead. Specially adding the appropriate `handler` to the `logger` and eventually logging to a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 3 you can replace the `print` function if you want (presumably at module-level), something like this.

```
_print = print
def print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False):
    # this test could probably be more sophisticated, to test for
    # any file whose file descriptor is the same as stdout or stderr
    if file in (sys.stdout, sys.stderr):
        output = io.StringIO()
        _print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=output)
        data = output.getvalue()
        if len(data) > 10000:
            # do the "are you sure?" interaction, however you want that to work
        _print(data, end='', file=file, flush=flush)
    else:
        _print(*objects, sep=sep, end=end, file=file, flush=flush)
```

To be honest you might not *want* to mess with builtins even though you can. But the principle is the same whatever you call it.

In Python 2 `print` doesn't take the same options (and it's a keyword so you can't intercept it and you can't call your function that even if you want to). So you can write a function that acts like Python 3 `print`, but either use Python 2 `print` as the underlying mechanism or do `from __future__ import print_function`. Also `StringIO` is in a module named `StringIO` instead of `io`.

Comment: Excellent idea! But with all due respect, is this really usefull for non experts?

Comment: @wolfrevo: I dunno. I'm dubious about the idea of adding interaction before printing, but I think *if* that's what you're really decided on doing then this code is about equally useful regardless of your level of expertise :-). Others have already covered the, "I'm not answering your actual question because you shouldn't be asking it" angle.

Answer (score 3):

Without writing your own print wrapper function, there is no easy way to limit the output from print. But a better idea (rather than using print) is to use the python logging system for debug statements, and redirect output to a file.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')
```

Comment: This is probably what @user3314418 really is searching for.

Comment: I second the fact that this is what the OP probably actually wants

Answer (score 2):

```
def mprint(*args,**kwargs):
   max_length = kwargs.get("max_length",1000)
   out_stream = kwargs.get("out",sys.stdout)
   s= " ".join(str(x) for x in args)
   half_of_max = max_length/2
   if len(s) > max_length:
       print "too much to print: %s...%s"%(s[:half_of_max ],s[max(len(s)-half_of_max ,half_of_max ):])
       return
   out_stream.write(s)
```

and instead of

```
print "hello world"
mprint("hello world",max_length=4)
```

or to write to a file

```
with open("asd.txt","w") as f:
    mprint("hello world",max_length=4,out=f)
```

this also has the added ability to insert data ... say if you wanted to insert timestamps before the print or what line called the print

in fact I use a similar function for all my logging (but the out is set globally rather than on call)

although the suggestion to use the actual [logging](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) package is a good one also :)